# How to Stack two Android elements in the center of the screen

Tags: android

I want the editText and the button to be stacked on top of each other in the center of the screen. There's obviously an incredibly simple method I'm missing. Here they stick to the top left of the screen. Any help would be appreciated. I tried relative layout as well but then they're on top of each other in the Z-axis.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   >

<EditText
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    />

<Button
    android:text="Go >"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative layout and put your elements on top of each others :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_main"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_main"
        android:text="Go >"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_main"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good solution, altough not exactly in the center of the screen, this layout has low depth, which is a good thing ;)

Comment: If the answer is fine, accept it for other users. If not, please add some details I didn't understand "this layout has low depth".

Comment: I'm not the original poster, but what I meant to say is that it is good practice to have a flat view hierarchy - which is the case in your layout. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054605/1208581) is similar, centers the elements exactly, but the layout has a larger depth of view hierarchy. Looks like OP found the answer himself and forgot about his question ;)

Comment: That layout goes like this...

http://tinypic.com/r/2vi4fvc/5

I want it in the center of the screen vertical as well.

Comment: Hey thanks, I changed your answer to fill_parent for the parent then it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android:gravity="center"` in your layout, it'll do the job for you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:text="Go Went Gone"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following data

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   >

<EditText
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:gravity="center"

    />

<Button
    android:text="Go >"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the edit text and Button in a vertical layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go >" />
</LinearLayout>
```